# Is there a drone kit that connects to a raspberry pi?

Tags: hardware, pi-2, pi-3, raspi-config

I am trying to build a drone with any amount of propellers(quadcopter,single,double,octo,etc.). I am not trying to do so much work of programming it, but I do want to assemble it. I'm looking for something with 'plug and play' type features.  Please let me know if there is a kit that is specifically designed for a raspberry pi(ANY KIND) to take flight.

Comment: Not a kit but the MagPi magazine featured a quadcopter with plans and parts list https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/magpi-issue-19-your-free-raspberry-pi-magazine-out-now/ This google search wil return many other examples https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry+pi+drone&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8. -1 for lack of effort.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here - these can get $$$ as there is more hardware needed to control drone on top of the Pi itself (motor controllers, gyro, other sensors,etc.
If you want a kit:

http://erlerobotics.com/blog/product/erle-copter-diy-kit/

If you want to build your own and use a pi for the brains only are these options:

https://erlerobotics.com/blog/product/erle-brain-v2/

There are some other products from erle robotics that utilize pi and no programming necessary. Also look up the navio2 - another good option.